# Item Web API An attempted to execute remote call was declided, because current mode is 'off' (Sitecore 8.2)

Tags: api, sitecore, sitecore8.2

I've enabled the Item Web API in my config but when I try to go to mysite.com/-/item/v1/?query=/sitecore/content/* I get a 404 error, and when I check the logs it says

> [Item Web API] An attempted to execute remote call was declided, because current mode is 'off'

I updated it in my Sitecore.ItemWebApi.config file:

```
  <site name="website">
    <patch:attribute name="itemwebapi.mode">StandardSecurity</patch:attribute>
    <patch:attribute name="itemwebapi.access">ReadOnly</patch:attribute>
    <patch:attribute name="itemwebapi.allowanonymousaccess">true</patch:attribute>
  </site>
```

I tried renaming Sitecore.ItemWebApi.config to z.Sitecore.ItemWebApi.config so it will be patched last, and i checked showconfig.aspx and it shows it being enable for my website

```
<site name="website" enableTracking="true" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/home" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="50MB" registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="25MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="10MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" cacheRenderingParameters="true" renderingParametersCacheSize="10MB" language="en" patch:source="Kofax.Sites.config" formsRoot="{F1F7AAB6-C8CE-422F-A214-F610C109FA63}" enableItemLanguageFallback="false" enableFieldLanguageFallback="false" itemwebapi.mode="StandardSecurity" itemwebapi.access="ReadOnly" itemwebapi.allowanonymousaccess="true" database="web"/>
```

Comment: Does this answer over on Sitecore StackExchange help? https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/6552/getting-item-from-the-sitecore-item-service-api-not-working-remotely-403-forbid

Comment: Or possibly this one on Sitecore StackExchange? https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/12037/sitecore-services-client-403-forbidden?noredirect=1

Comment: Does Sitecore.ItemWebApi.Pipelines.HttpRequest.SetRuntimeSettings run after the SiteResolver?

Comment: @JayS yes, changing the SecurityPolicy to ServicesOnPolicy fixed it!